# python 3 import TypeError error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having a bizarre app startup error and was wondering if someone might know how to debug/resolve it.

I'm running a Flask app using python 3. I kick things off by running: `python manage.py runserver` and the stacktrace below is generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projectbase/manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    create_tables()
  File "/projectbase/myproject/__init__.py", line 15, in create_tables
    from myproject.models.util import Weekday, weekday_type
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 742, in __exit__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 742, in <genexpr>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

***The problem is, when I run it in a debugger and setup breakpoints the problem goes away. But if I run it without debugging the problem exists.***

For further reference the `create_tables()` function called by manage.py code/file looks like:

```
from myproject.app import app
from myproject.app import db

def create_tables():
    from myproject.models.util import Weekday, weekday_type
    from myproject.models.activity import Activity, activities_tags, Occurrence, Tag

    db.create_all()
```

And further `Weekday` and `weekday_type` code in question looks like:

```
from myproject.app import db
from myproject.models.enum import DeclEnum

class Weekday(DeclEnum):
    Sunday    = 'Sunday', {'offset': 0}
    Monday    = 'Monday', {'offset': 1}
    Tuesday   = 'Tuesday', {'offset': 2}
    Wednesday = 'Wednesday', {'offset': 3}
    Thursday  = 'Thursday', {'offset': 4}
    Friday    = 'Friday', {'offset': 5}
    Saturday  = 'Saturday', {'offset': 6}

weekday_type = Weekday.db_type(metadata=db.metadata)
weekday_type.register_with_psycopg(db.engine)
```

The `DeclEnum` type I use is basically just copied from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbirtwell/aaccdb7972e1a7ed094b).

The only adjustment I made to the code was to make `DeclEnum` a little more flexible so it can take a dictionary of values rather than just a `value` and `description`. Other than that I changed nothing.

Any ideas what's going on here? Since the act of debugging it *fixes* things, I don't know how to go about getting to the bottom of the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is misleading.

Looking at the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbirtwell/aaccdb7972e1a7ed094b) I linked to in the original question

The method `register_with_psycopg()` works only if the enum type has first been created in the database. I was calling the method before the type had been created. By changing the ordering of things during app startup the error went away.